# Delete/Drop nested columns within dataset

Tags: filtering, dataset

I have sorted some data into a dataset, but when exporting the dataset to be an external file I would only need certain columns within the dataset. I would like to drop the everything within the "Repeats" column (nested columns within etc) and the "Fitting Parameter" column. I know keyDrop can be used for outer keys for example, it would work fine at removing "Experiment Identifier", however I don't think it works for nested keys. An example dataset (which is empty) is coded underneath. The reason for wanting to do this is to save on storage space, as these columns would contain raw data that is no longer needed.

````
NumberOfBlocks = 100;
NumberOfRepeats = 2;
NumberOfWaveforms = 2;
NumberOfExperiments = 10;

(*Create dataset for data*)
Blocks = Table[<|"Block Number" -> i, 
    "Parameters" -> <|"Freq" -> 5, "Drifted Freq" -> {}|>, 
    "Waveforms" -> 
     Table[<|"Waveform Type" -> j, 
       "Repeats" -> 
        Table[<|"Repeat number" -> k, "Spectrum" -> {}, 
          "Fitting Parameters" -> {}|>, {k, NumberOfRepeats}], 
       "Fitting Parameter" -> {}, "Spectral Splitting" -> {}|>, {j, 
       NumberOfWaveforms}]|>, {i, NumberOfBlocks}];

DatasetRawData = 
  Table[<|"Experiment" -> i, 
    "Experiment Identifier" -> ToString["Example " <> ToString[i]], 
    "Data" -> Blocks|>, {i, NumberOfExperiments}];
(*End of Dataset creation*)
DatasetRawData // Dataset
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `Query` (or `Dataset`) "part application" operator syntax *{part->operator}* to apply `KeyDrop` at the appropriate level:

```
DatasetRawData //
  Query[
    All
  , {"Data"->{All->{"Waveforms"->KeyDrop[{"Repeats","Fitting Parameter"}]}}}
  ] //
  Dataset
```

or we could use `MapAt` to do the same:

```
MapAt[
  KeyDrop[{"Repeats", "Fitting Parameter"}]
, DatasetRawData
, {All, "Data", All, "Waveforms"}
] // Dataset
```

Both return this result:
[image: dataset snapshot]

If desired, these strategies can also be applied directly to a dataset object (named `DatasetRaw` in these examples):

```
DatasetRaw[
  All
, {"Data"->{All->{"Waveforms"->KeyDrop[{"Repeats","Fitting Parameter"}]}}}
]
```

```
MapAt[
  KeyDrop[{"Repeats", "Fitting Parameter"}]
, DatasetRaw
, {All, "Data", All, "Waveforms"}
]
```